# ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([16])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([13456, 1])) is deprecated

Tags: python, pytorch

My code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qjfy2OsHYewhHDej-W83CMNercB7o7r8?usp=sharing

the error: ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([16])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([13456, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.

the dataset consists of 2 folders: 0 and 1, and in each of these two folders, there’re about 2500 512*512 images and a json file for each image.

the code was from the pytorch gan tutorial, i just changed the dataset.

I wonder where does the 13456 come from?

Answer (score 1):

The original code is intended for 64 x 64 images, not 512 x 512 ones. To fix the problem, you have to either downsize the images to 64 x 64 or modify the discriminator and the generator.

Answer (score 0):

```
label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
```

This creates an array of size b_size (16) filled with real_label (1) .

```
output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
output = output.unsqueeze(1)
```

The output is of size (x,1) where x is the number of outputs in your last convolutional network, which is not equal to the batch size.